# Persistent BottomNavigationBar with Routing in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, navigation

I have a hard time implementing a persistent [BottomNavigationBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html) in Flutter. My goal is to create a app with several screens and therefore several routes (minimal example):

[image: app structure for minimal example]

I found [this](https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-case-study-multiple-navigators-with-bottomnavigationbar-90eb6caa6dbf) medium article and after struggling a bit with the implementation, I thought that I found the perfect solution. **BUT as I wanted to implement a logout function that sends the user back to the *LoginScreen* the routing doesn't work as expected...**

[image: gif]

As you see in the gif, the problem occours after clicking on the logout button. Instead of navigating back to the *LoginScreen*, the *LoginScreen* get's embedded into the *MainScreen* with the BottomNavigationBar.

**How can I change this behaviour? I thought I would remove all routes with `pushAndRemoveUntil`...**

```
// Navigate back to the LoginScreen (this doesn't work as expected...)
          Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => LoginScreen(),
              ),
              (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

Here is a minimal reproducable example: https://github.com/klasenma/persistent_bottomnavigationbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempts, I managed to solve the problem. I needed to save the context of the *MainScreen* (index.dart -> holds the BottomNavigationBar).

```
class ContextKeeper {
  static BuildContext buildContext;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    buildContext = context;
  }
}
```

lib/screens/main/index.dart:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  ContextKeeper().init(context); // Save the context
}
```

Then change

```
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen(),),(Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

to

```
 Navigator.of(ContextKeeper.buildContext).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(LoginScreen.id, (route) => false);
```

and it work's.